# iis , difficulty with .Net framework version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-framework-version

I am developing an application in asp net mvc , this application used the version 4.5 of the .Net framework, in my own iis only version 4.0 , already installed on my server version 4.5 , however in my pool does not appear this option and I'm being bombed by the following error:

**The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.**

Stack trace:

**ConfigurationErrorsException: The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.
   System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.ValidateCompilerVersionFor40AndAbove(String compilerVersion) +306
   System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.ValidateCompilerVersionFor40AndAbove() +17
   System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.EnsureFrameworkNamesInitialized() +212
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +288
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +367
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +982
[HttpException (0x80004005): The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +771**

Comment: .NET 4.5 applications can run in the .NET 4.0 pool.

Comment: ok , so I 've read in some places , but I do not understand the error reason above happen